# is there any possible way to trig the tooltip without any tap function in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want to Display the tooltip message as soon as my text field validation condition goes false without any onPress or onLongpress method. is it possible? if yes, then how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

use `onChanged` attribute in TextField make validation happen on each modification

when itsn't valid show you tooltip

Comment: I did that, seems like that doesn't work for me. I want a message that the toolTip shows when you tap on it without taping on it.

Comment: make ValueListenableBuilder<bool> child will contain textfield  and onChange test if textfield valid if not showTooltipNotifier.value = true
and builder  if  showTooltip == true  Tooltip(message ="...",child:child)
else return child